# How to take all values from a single cell

Tags: google-sheets

I have the following data

```
X    f1     f2     f3
1    20   20/5/2   3
2    0    10/5/0   7
3    15   20/2/1   3
4    30   80/0/9   3
```

I want to make `SUM()` of all values in `f2` column but it gives me an error because of the `/`.

How can I take each value, separately?

[image: 2nd question]

Plus, how to get each relative percentage of each cell in `f2`? For example, the first cell of f2 would be `74,07 / 18,52 / 7,41` taken from doing (20/27 - 5/27- 2/27)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=INDEX(SUM(IFERROR(SPLIT(F1:F; "/"); 0)*1))
```

### update:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(C1:C="";;SUBSTITUTE(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(ROUND(
 IFERROR(SPLIT(C1:C; "/")/MMULT(1*IFERROR(SPLIT(C1:C; "/")); 
 SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(SPLIT(C1:C; "/")); 1;;)^0))*100; 2));;9^9)); " "; " / ")))
```

[image]

Comment: thank you! and to get the percentage of each value in each cell in `f2`? For example, the first cell of `f2` would be `74,07/18,52/7,41` taken from doing (`20/27` - `5/27`- `2/27`)

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: sure! I've added it in the main question, thank you!

Comment: I know I shouldn't answer with "thank you" comments, but you have put a lot of effort and time to help me, so really I appreciate it so much. Thank you!!!!